# MUI custom style using styled() suddenly disappeared

Tags: material-ui

MUI custom style using `styled()` suddenly disappeared...
I made custom Button, Typography, Container, etc. using 'import {style} from '@mui/styles', but the style properties that were working fine do not work after a few days. It works only when I put each style in the `sx prop`. The properties that do not work when using  `style()` I've checked so far are `border`, `font`, `display: "flex"`.

Does anyone know why this issue is happening? I'm in trouble because my style suddenly broke in many places...

Examples are follows:

- Collection of codes that used to work but don't work now

```
import React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/styles';
import { Container, Typorgaphy, Button } from '@mui/material';

export default function Example() {
    <VerticalContainer maxWidth="sm">
    ...
    </VerticalContainer>

    <TitleTypography>
    ...
    </TitleTypography>

    <TangerineOutlinedButton color="primary">
    ...
    </TangerineOutlinedButton>
}

const VerticalContainer = styled(Container)({
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
})

const TitleTypography = styled(Typography)({
    fontWeight: 700,
    fontFamily: "Impact",
    fontSize: "1.25rem"
})

const TangerineOutlinedButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) =>({
    border: `3px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
    borderRadius: "0.75rem",
    minWidth: "6rem",
    maxWidth: "7rem",
    height: "2rem",
    paddingRight: 0,
}))
```

- So the code that I modified...

```
import React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/styles';
import { Container, Button } from '@mui/material';

export default function Example() {
    <Container maxWidth="sm" sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center" }}>
    ...
    </Container>

    <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 700, fontFamily: "Impact", fontSize: "1.25rem" }}
    ...
    </Typography>

    <TangerineOutlinedButton color="primary" sx={{ border: "3px solid #FFBB00", borderRadius: "0.75rem" }}>
    ...
    </TangerineOutlinedButton>
}

const TangerineOutlinedButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) =>({
    minWidth: "6rem",
    maxWidth: "rem",
    height: "2rem",
    paddingRight: 0,
}))
```

Comment: What component doesn't work? do you have any error?

Comment: @NearHuscarl It's not that an error occurs, the style that originally worked well in `styled()` doesn't work, so there is a problem that I have to put them one by one in in the `sx prop`.

Comment: @NearHuscarl Certain styles don't seem to work regardless of the component. The components I checked so far were Button, Typography, and Container, and the styles that didn't work were styles related to border, font, and flexbox.